# Angular-SummerNote not working to set value with the controller context

Tags: angularjs, summernote

I am using component based architecture but [angular-summernote](https://github.com/summernote/angular-summernote) is not working with controller context.

Ex: `<summernote>$ctrl.setvalue<summernote>`

**Edit**
It is displaying the text rather than interpreting it.

```
<p>{{$ctrl.test1}}</p>

<summernote>{{$ctrl.setvalue}}</summernote>

**O/P**

<p>Hello</p>
<summernote>{{$ctrl.setvalue}}</summernote>
```

**EDIT 2**
Here is my Module

```
angular.module('SecondPage', ['summernote'])
```

Here is my Component

```
angular.module('SecondPage').
component('SecondPage', {
    templateUrl: 'pqr/abc.html',
    controller:  function ArticlePageController()
    {            
        var self = this;
        self.test2 = 'Hello';
        self.checkme="Check Me";
    }
});
```

Comment: have you tried `{{$ctrl.setvalue}}`?

Comment: yes, i did that too.

Comment: and what does it output when you use the expression?

Comment: It output the same

Comment: that doesn't make sense.  when you put `<summernote>{{$ctrl.setvalue}}</summernote>`, your output is `$ctrl.setvalue`??  are you getting any errors in the console?

Comment: It output the same {{$ctrl.setvalue}} No errors in console.

Comment: well, if angular is outputting the expression brackets, that *generally* means that angular didn't load, for some reason.  you should try to create a [mcve] that demonstrates how angular could be loaded but not processing it's expressions.

Comment: Please check the edit

Comment: that's not a [mcve];  there is nothing showing an angular app or controller, or what those properties are supposed to be set to.

Comment: Please check Edit 2 Claies